# ImageButton click listener does not work

Tags: java, android

I have my Custom Adapter because I have a `ImageButton` and want to set the `onClickListener`.

The problem is when I click for example the element in the position 0 it returns the element in position 3; I do not understand why..

This is the Custom Adapter:

```
   public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {


    private final Activity context;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> mlist;
    private String mNome;
    private String mCognome;
    private String mTitolo;
    private String mInfo;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    View view;
    ArrayList<Integer> map = new ArrayList<>();
    HashMap<String, Object> e;

    public CustomAdapter(Activity context,ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> mlist){

        this.context = context;
        this.mlist=mlist;
        mInflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

    }



    public class ViewHolder {

        public ImageButton mImageButton;
        public TextView mTitleView;
        public TextView mNomeView;
        public TextView mCognomeView;
        public TextView mInfoView;



    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mlist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        Log.d("POSITION GET",Integer.toString(position));

        if (mlist != null && position >= 0 && position < getCount()) {
            Log.d("POSITION GET",Integer.toString(position));
            return mlist.get(position);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {


        if (mlist != null && position >= 0 && position < getCount()) {
            return Integer.parseInt((String)mlist.get(position).get("id"));
        }
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        view = convertView;
        e = (HashMap<String, Object>) getItem(position);

        if (view == null) {

            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_avvisi, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.mImageButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
            viewHolder.mCognomeView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cognome);
            viewHolder.mNomeView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nome);
            viewHolder.mTitleView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titolo);
            viewHolder.mInfoView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.info);

            viewHolder.mImageButton.setClickable(true);






            view.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.mImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                String nome = e.get("Nome").toString();

                Log.d("TAG", nome);

                Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, (String) "Avviso Scuola: " + nome + " " +
                                mCognome + "\n" +
                                mTitolo + "\n" +
                                mInfo
                );
                shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                context.startActivity(shareIntent);


            }
        });


        viewHolder.mCognomeView.setText(e.get("Cognome").toString());
        viewHolder.mNomeView.setText(e.get("Nome").toString());
        viewHolder.mTitleView.setText(e.get("Titolo").toString());
        viewHolder.mInfoView.setText(e.get("Info").toString());



        return view;
    }
```

And in the fragment i have:

```
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> mlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

    ...

for (int i = 1; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                    Gson gson = new Gson();


                    Avv mAvv = gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(array.getJSONObject(i)), Avv.class);

                    map.put("id", String.valueOf(i));
                    map.put("Name", mAvv.getNome());
                    map.put("Surname", mAvv.getCognome());
                    map.put("Title", mAvv.getTitolo());
                    map.put("Info",  mAvv.getTesto());


                    mlist.add(map);
                }

...


     CustomAdapter mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(),mlist);
     list.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, (String) "Avviso " + tx.getText().toString());
```

You are using data used from the Views that are recycled. Don't do that, ever. Instead get that data from the ArrayList

```
mlist.get(postion)....
```

You have to add the `final` declaration to the position in order for it to be accessible inside the `onClick` method

`public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` {

Comment: You can, but you have to make the position final.   getView(**final** int position

Comment: Hi, the problem is the position (i have try with                     Log.d("POSITION", Integer.toString(position)); is only 0-1-2 or 3.. and after that it return to 0 but the element in the list is 4...so the other element is cut out..Can you help?
)

Comment: ListView is recycling views and you will see the position of the view that is currently being drawn. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works

Comment: Hi, i read but for now i'm not found solution.. i update my question